# iOS In App Purchase Model

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am having a problem trying to get the business model of my client to work with iOS in app purchases. We are using Parse.com as a backend for this app.

There are two type of users for this application consumers and posters. Posters are able to post an add for a business and the consumers are able to view those ads. The information for the ads are being stored in the Parse backend.

The problem that I am having is this.

The client wants to have 4 different durations for each ad 1 month 3 month 6 month and 1 year. I have set these up on the iTunes connect account as consumables because the duration it stored in Parse.

I can make the purchase the product just fine but the problem is that I have no way of tying a transaction to a specific add I can only determine which of the products (1 month, 3 month, etc that they bought) and the user can have multiple ads.

I also have the problem of since the ad information is stored on Parse I cannot invalidate it unless the user opens their device.

Comment: FYI your IAPs in this case sound like they should be non-renewable subscriptions, not consumables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this by making your in-app purchase an intermediate "currency" such as "credits" - The user then purchases a number of credits and when they post an ad it consumes the appropriate number of credits from their balance.

This way you do not need to associate a particular ad with a particular purchase - you simply verify the balance is sufficient for, say, a 3 month posting, deduct the credits from the balance and put the ad in the database with the appropriate duration field.

Comment: This is a good idea I will think about this some more. Thank You